# Como faço para impossibilitar que a pessoa submeta o formulário várias vezes no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Programei um site no laravel, mas não consigo incrementar uma função que impossibilite que o usuário envie o formulária várias vezes clicando no botão.

Comment: Olá Rick, é importante que você adicione seu código à pergunta para possibilitar a visualização de seu erro.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, você pode colocar um código javascript para bloquear o próximo clique.

Segue um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true">Enviar Formulario</button>
```

Obs: Coloque sempre o código (se possível) para que seja mais fácil de solucionar o seu problema.

Grande abraço, espero ter ajudado!